# Display SVG (from string) on Python Pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, svg, pygame, pygame-surface

I have an SVG graphic represented in a string

```
svg_string='<svg height="100" width="500"><ellipse cx="240" cy="50" rx="220" ry="30" style="fill:yellow" /><ellipse cx="220" cy="50" rx="190" ry="20" style="fill:white" /></svg>'
```

I want to display the graphics represented by `svg_string`, which is 2 ellipses, on a window initiated from Python.

The pseudo code of which should be something like

```
import pygame


def display_svg_figure(screen, svg_string):
    #   Code that draws the rendered SVG string on
    #   the screen
    pass

background_colour = (255, 255, 255)
(width, height) = (900, 900)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Display SVG')
screen.fill(background_colour)

pygame.display.flip()

svg_string='<svg height="100" width="500"><ellipse cx="240" cy="50" rx="220" ry="30" style="fill:yellow" /><ellipse cx="220" cy="50" rx="190" ry="20" style="fill:white" /></svg>'
display_svg_figure(screen, svg_string)


running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
```

I am basically looking at an implementation of the method `display_svg_figure(screen,svg_string)`

I am open to a using non pygame libraries too as long as it follows the simple interfaces of the following and is possible to include it in pygame

```
from SOME_LIBRARY import SOME_COMPONENT

svg_string="......"
SOME_COMPONENT.display(svg_string)
```

I have already looked at `pynanosvg` but that's no longer supported and is failing so does not suffice my need.

The solution given in [Display SVG file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63139025) does not seem to fit the bill as it is not working in PyGame. If someone can make it work kindly let me know.

Comment: To be clear, do you want to display the _text_ of the SVG string, and not the graphic it represents?  If so, the solution wouldn't care if the string was in SVG format or not.

Comment: @PeterO. To clarify it should render the graphics it represents. For instance I need the output to be a window showing 2 ellipses as mentioned in the svg_string. I have edited the initial query to bring my ask out more clearly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How to read an [Scalable  Vector Graphics (SVG)](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics) file is answered at [SVG rendering in a PyGame application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120584/svg-rendering-in-a-pygame-application/64598021#64598021).

---

**SVG files are supported with Pygame version 2.0**. Since Version 2.0.2, SDL Image supports SVG ([Scalable Vector Graphics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics)) files (see [SDL_image 2.0](https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image)). Therefore, with pygame version 2.0.1, SVG files can be loaded into a [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) object with  [`pygame.image.load()`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html) from a stream ([`io.BytesIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#binary-i-o)):

```py
svg_string = '<svg height="100" width="500"><ellipse cx="240" cy="50" rx="220" ry="30" style="fill:yellow" /><ellipse cx="220" cy="50" rx="190" ry="20" style="fill:white" /></svg>'
pygame_surface = pygame.image.load(io.BytesIO(svg_string.encode()))
```

Minimal example:

[image]

```py
import pygame
import io

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 200))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

svg_string = '<svg height="100" width="500"><ellipse cx="240" cy="50" rx="220" ry="30" style="fill:yellow" /><ellipse cx="220" cy="50" rx="190" ry="20" style="fill:white" /></svg>'
pygame_surface = pygame.image.load(io.BytesIO(svg_string.encode()))

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    window.fill((255, 255, 255))
    window.blit(pygame_surface, pygame_surface.get_rect(center = window.get_rect().center))
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```

---

Before Pygame 2, you had to implement [Scalable Vector Graphics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics) loading with other libraries. There are multiple possibilities to render a SVG string.

A simple possibility is to use *svglib*. Install [svglib](https://pypi.org/project/svglib/):

```
pip install svglib
```

Write a function that parses and rasterizes an SVG string and and creates a [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) object:

```py
from svglib.svglib import svg2rlg
import io

def load_svg(svg_string):
    svg_io = io.StringIO(svg_string)
    drawing = svg2rlg(svg_io)
    str = drawing.asString("png")
    byte_io = io.BytesIO(str)
    return pygame.image.load(byte_io)
```

However, there seems to be a problem with transparent backgrounds. There is an issue about this topic [How to make the png background transparent? #171](https://github.com/deeplook/svglib/issues/171).

An alternative solution (which is apparently slower) is to use  [CairoSVG](https://cairosvg.org/). With the function `cairosvg.svg2png`, an [Vector Graphics (SVG)](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics) files can be directly converted to an [Portable Network Graphics (PNG)] file

Install [CairoSVG](https://pypi.org/project/CairoSVG/).

```
pip install CairoSVG
```

Write a function that converts a SVF file to a PNG ([`ByteIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html)) and creates a [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) object may look as follows:

```py
import cairosvg
import io

def load_svg(filename):
    new_bites = cairosvg.svg2png(url = filename)
    byte_io = io.BytesIO(new_bites)
    return pygame.image.load(byte_io)
```

See also [svgsurf.py](https://gist.github.com/zgoda/16c4bb767a085743251503471c1faeb1).

---

Minimal example:

[image]

```py
from svglib.svglib import svg2rlg
import pygame
import io

def load_svg_svglib(svg_string):
    svg_io = io.StringIO(svg_string)
    drawing = svg2rlg(svg_io)
    str = drawing.asString("png")
    byte_io = io.BytesIO(str)
    svg_surf = pygame.image.load(byte_io)
    return svg_surf

def display_svg_figure(screen, svg_string):
    surf = load_svg_svglib(svg_string)
    screen.blit(surf, (0, 0))

background_colour = (255, 255, 255)
(width, height) = (900, 900)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Display SVG')
screen.fill(background_colour)

svg_string='<svg height="100" width="500"><ellipse cx="240" cy="50" rx="220" ry="30" style="fill:yellow" /><ellipse cx="220" cy="50" rx="190" ry="20" style="fill:white" /></svg>'
display_svg_figure(screen, svg_string)

running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    pygame.display.flip()
```