# PySide2: Load SVG from Variable rather than from file

Tags: python, pyside2

I want to display an `svg` file using PySide. But I would prefer not having to create a `file.svg` and then load it using `QSvgWidget`

Rather I just have the file contents of the `file.svg` contents already stored in a variable as a string.

How would I go about directly loading the SVG from the variable rather than form the file.

Best

Comment: Take a look at `PySide6.QtGui`, especially the `QSvgRenderer` method, then use `PySide6.QtWidgets`

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52837657/2314737

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the string to a [QByteArray](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-6/PySide6/QtCore/QByteArray.html#PySide6.QtCore.PySide6.QtCore.QByteArray).

From the [QSvgWidget.load](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-6/PySide6/QtSvgWidgets/QSvgWidget.html#PySide6.QtSvgWidgets.PySide6.QtSvgWidgets.QSvgWidget.load) documentation:

> `PySide6.QtSvgWidgets.QSvgWidget.load(contents)`
>
> PARAMETERS:
>
> contents – `PySide6.QtCore.QByteArray`

Here's a full demo:

```
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PySide6.QtSvgWidgets import QSvgWidget
from PySide6.QtCore import QByteArray
import sys

svg_string="""<svg width="50" height="50">
    <circle cx="25" cy="25" r="20"/>
</svg>"""
svg_bytes = QByteArray(svg_string)
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
svgWidget = QSvgWidget()
svgWidget.renderer().load(svg_bytes)
svgWidget.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @user2314737 us correct, however does not work exactly in PySide2. Below are the changes that make it work also in PySide2

```py
from PySide2.QtCore import QByteArray
from PySide2 import QtSvg
svg_string="""<svg width="50" height="50">
    <circle cx="25" cy="25" r="20"/>
</svg>"""
svg_bytes = QByteArray(bytes(svg_string,"utf-8"))
svgWidget = QtSvg.QSvgWidget()
svgWidget.renderer().load(svg_bytes)
```